# Linkedin adding more images to the og: image

Tags: url, share, linkedin-api

I have correctly added my tag og:image and when i share via linkedin, it use the og image and two more images of the site.

How do we ignore those two images of the site?

FYI, Facebook, Twitter are working correctly.